# Why angular throws an exception "Unexpected quantifier" when I create an instance of RegEx?

Tags: regex, angularjs

If i try to create regex anywhere in my code angular throws an error "Unexpected quantifier"? Why? This regex is valid, tested and works but if I try

```
var p = new RegExp("^(.{1,19}\*|\*.{1,19}|(?!\*).{1,20})$");
```

angular will throw an error. However this simple, dummy regex will not.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^(.)$");
```

This leads me to believe that it is a matter of escaping of characters or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a JavaScript error, not one produced by the angular framework. The regular expression you provided is invalid, as the error message states. Specifically, you need to escape backslashes in string literals. Your current expression evaluates to this:

```
^(.{1,19}*|*.{1,19}|(?!*).{1,20})$
```

What you probably want is this:

```
var p = new RegExp("^(.{1,19}\\*|\\*.{1,19}|(?!\\*).{1,20})$");
```

Resulting in the following regular expression:

```
^(.{1,19}\*|\*.{1,19}|(?!\*).{1,20})$
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslash in the Regex:

```
new RegExp("^(.{1,19}\\*|\\*.{1,19}|(?!\\*).{1,20})$");
```

This code will throw an exception:

```
new RegExp("\*.");
// SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*./: Nothing to repeat
```

Because the string evaluates to

```
"*."
```

There is no character class before the `*` quantifier, so the expression is invalid.